# MSTest multithreading with ManualResetEvent - Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain error

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, mstest, appdomain

I am running a unit test to test functionality that involves ManualResetEvents.

The actual unit test (and the real code) itself runs successfully. However after the unit test finishes, I am getting an **AppDomainUnloadedException was unhandled**  - **Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain** error.

At first I thought this might be due to some other code, but upon further investigation, it seems like it's related to the usage of multithreading here?

I've tried some suggestions I found, such as setting execution mode to MTA, etc. but the error still occurs.

Is there a way to fix this, or at least suppress this error from occurring at the end of the successful unit test run?